# Check if the user has clicked inside a specific div in a component

Tags: dom, angular

I have got a global click event in my application.

```
  host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
    },
```

Everytime the user clicks, my handleClick function will execute. I want to check if the user has clicked in a specific div. I've tried with the following:

```
 handleClick(event){
    console.log(event.target===document.getElementsByClassName("drop_down_wrapper")
}
```

But this does not work. I've also tried to get hold of a specific div by using ElementRef but I only managed to get hold of the native element of my div. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HtmlCollection, so you might want to use index to access individual items:

```
handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target === document.getElementsByClassName("drop_down_wrapper")[0]
}
```

Or better use querySelector method:

```
handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target === document.querySelector(".drop_down_wrapper")
}
```

However, if your div have inner HTML you would probably need to check if the clicked target is a child of the div or not:

```
var target = e.target;
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".drop_down_wrapper");

while (target != wrapper && target !== document) {
    target = target.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Add a click handler to the particular div you want to listen on, and add

```
event.stopPropogation();
```

This should prevent your document click handler from firing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solution also worked fine!